# Get the number of COUNT in a dept_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table employee and department table. My query runs well, now I want to get the number of COUNTS into the dept_id in employee table. Here is the structure of my table

Table employee
[image]

And my department table
[image]

Now my script below here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Query</h1>

    <?php require "connection.php";?>

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT department.dept_id, result1.salary 
                FROM department,  
                (SELECT employee.dept_id, 
                SUM(employee.salary) salary 
                FROM employee  
                GROUP BY employee.dept_id
                ORDER BY employee.dept_id
                ) 
                result1 
                WHERE result1.dept_id = department.dept_id;  
                ";
       $result =$conn->query($sql);
    
    ?>
    
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               
                <td>dept id</td>
                <td>count</td>
                <td>sum_of_salary</td>
              
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if($result->rowCount() > 0): ?>
            <?php while($row = $result->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
                <tr>
                   
                    <td><?= $row['dept_id']; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?= $row['salary']; ?></td>
                  
                </tr>
               
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif;?>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of my code is here
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the built in  count` function in mysql?

Comment: yes i have but it seems its now working hmmm

Comment: Can you try the answer I posted and let me know if it works.

Comment: @kks21199 okay i will try sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` ([read here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php)) to get the count so your SQL query will be,

```
SELECT department.dept_id, result1.salary, result1.countEmp
                FROM department,  
                (SELECT employee.dept_id, 
                SUM(employee.salary) salary,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(employee.emp_id)) countEmp
                FROM employee  
                GROUP BY employee.dept_id
                ORDER BY employee.dept_id
                ) 
                result1 
                WHERE result1.dept_id = department.dept_id;
```

Comment: This is correct, but the OP asked to count number of employees in each department I think.

Comment: how to display the count into my while loop?

Comment: @jonasdev yea I misread the question. I have updated my answer

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper please look at the updated answer. You can access it using `$row['countEmp']`

Comment: `ORDER BY employee.dept_id` isn't useful here